# Fixed position doesn't stay fixed in other browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this icon for exiting modal which stays perfectly fixed when scrolling down on Chrome, but I noticed it doesn't work in other browsers like Firefox and Safari. 
I also notited that the icon is little off in the right corner but after split second it reposition itself where it should be. Any ideas what's causing this? Is it because the parent which is the modal is of position fixed and you can't have fixed position inside fixed container? I'm still learning HTML.

```css
.outer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 70px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 3;
  right: 0;
  margin: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
}

.inner {
  width: inherit;
  text-align: center;
}


.inner::before, .inner::after {

    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    height: 1px;
    width: inherit;
    background: #FFC107;
    left: 0;
    transition: all .3s ease-in;

#animatedModal3 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  z-index: 9999;
  opacity: 1;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

.inner::after {

    bottom: 50%;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);

}

.inner::before {

    top: 50%;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);

}
```

```html
<div id="animatedModal3" class="bg-black">

  <div class="close-animatedModal3 py-3 bg-black">
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner">
        <label class="label2">Back</label>
          </div>
          </div>

          </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a bracket that is not closed here .inner::before, .inner::after {...